# Why are questions downvoted because of grammatical errors?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, grammar

Of what use is it to the community for someone to take the time to down-vote a question I posted because of two typos?

Comment: Why do you think that the typos caused the downvotes? Furthermore, we have no context since you haven't provided any links. Lastly, "downgrading" does not mean the same thing as "downvoting".

Comment: A question completely riddled with typos and mistakes in grammar might well be downvoted. Especially if it's very long and is essentially impossible to read. That would make it a bad question. (And it would also likely be closed as unclear.) But it's *highly* unlikely (although not impossible) that just a couple of typos would result in a downvote.

Answer (score 11):

I will bet you dollars to donuts that this didn't happen.

Not that I'm disputing your question was downvoted. That's plain for anyone to see.

What neither you nor anyone else can see is *why* someone downvoted a question, so I'm betting that it wasn't two typos that were the motivation behind the downvotes.

The tooltip on the downvote arrow contains an explanation of the reason(s) why someone might have downvoted your question:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

If serious typos made a question unclear, then that would certainly be a valid reason to downvote. But it's extremely unlikely that two typos would cause that problem.

Unless, of course, you were asking a question on Stack Overflow, and the two typos were in code, and they were causing an obvious error, thus making the question neither useful to anyone else nor indicative of research effort on your part.

Either way, a downvote is meant to be a signal that there is something wrong with your post—that you should take another look at it, and see if there is something (or multiple somethings) that you can improve. If you've taken a couple of hard looks, and yet still can't find anything that can be improved, then you should just move on and ignore the downvotes. They're just expressions of opinion, after all.

---

So, I did some research, and [I dug up the question you are probably referring to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55944488/determine-ip-address-of-a-guest-vm-on-virtualbox). That question was indeed downvoted, and indeed [someone edited it to fix two typos](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55944488/revisions). However, you have no way of knowing whether those two events were connected. You don't even know if it was the editor who cast the vote.

Well, you now know who cast the *second* downvote, but only because I'm telling you it was me. The question is *completely* off-topic for Stack Overflow. It has nothing to do with programming within the scope defined by [our Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Therefore, I have also closed it as off-topic. I'd also bet that its being off-topic is the reason why the first downvote was cast.

Comment: I knew it was you who down vote all those posts!

Comment: I think it would be helpful if the person down-voting would be required to leave a comment as to why it was down-voted. Thank you for letting me know it was off topic, though.

Comment: Mandatory feedback on downvotes has been proposed many, many times. [Here is a summary of why it is always declined](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin). @Vietyank

Comment: It would have saved all this chatter